# Need help figuring out why this object is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, oop

I'm writing a game and what I have so far for the object that represents the game's playing board is

```
// define game object
function Game ( board, numBlocks ) {
    //     board: Raphael object that the snake will live on
    // numBlocks: Number of blocks both horizontally AND vertically -- the grid structure should be squares

    this.board = board;
    this.numBlocks = numBlocks;
    this.snake; // Snake object on the board
    this.openCoords = []; // coordinates on which the snake is not living at the moment
    this.food = null; // food element on board

    this.getAllCoords = function ( )
    {
        // returns list of all grid coordinates on the canvas, 
        // e.g. [{x:0,y:0}, {x:0,y:1}, ..., {x:15, y:15}] on a 16x16 board
        var retList = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.numBlocks; ++i)
            for (var j = 0; j < this.numBlocks; ++j)
                retList.push({ x : i, y : j });
        return retList;
    }

    this.Snake = function ( )
    {

        // start with 3 blocks in the center-ish
        var blockWidth = this.board.getSize().width / this.numBlocks;
        var centerCoord = this.openCoords[this.openCoords.length / 2];
        var headElement = new elementOnGrid(
                board.rect(centerCoord.x * blockWidth, centerCoord.y * blockWidth, blockWidth, blockWidth, 5).attr('fill', '#19FF19'),
                centerCoord.x,
                centerCoord.y
            );
    }

    this.elementOnGrid = function ( elem, xpos, ypos )
    {
        //       elem: Rapael element (see: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element) 
        // xpos, ypos: x and y grid coordinates of the current position of the element 
        return { elem: elem, pos : [xpos, ypos] };
    }

    this.placeFood = function ( )
    {
        var randIndex = randInt(0, this.openCoords.length);
        var randCoord = this.openCoords[randIndex]; // get random x-y grid coordinate from list of open coordinates
        var blockWidth = this.board.getSize().width / this.numBlocks; // width in pixels of a block on the board
        if (this.food == null) // if food element hasn't been initialized
        {
            // initialize the food element
            this.food = new this.elementOnGrid( 
                    board.circle(randCoord.x * blockWidth + blockWidth / 2, randCoord.y * blockWidth + blockWidth / 2, blockWidth / 2).attr('fill', '#cf6a4c'),  // place circle in random location on the board (see http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.circle)
                    randCoord.x, 
                    randCoord.y
            ); // set food to be new element of type elementOnGrid
        }
        else // food element has been initialized (game is in play)
        {
            // move the food element

            // ... 
        }

        this.openCoords.splice(1, randIndex); // remove from openCoords the element that    

    }


    this.startNew = function ( ) {
        this.openCoords = this.getAllCoords();
        this.snake = new this.Snake();
        this.placeFood();       
    }
}
```

and my problem is that I'm getting a

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSize' of undefined

on the line

```
var blockWidth = this.board.getSize().width / this.numBlocks;
```

when I run

```
SG = new Game(snakeBoard, 16);
SG.startNew();
```

to start the game.

I know this is some type of scope/inheritance/hoisting/etc. issue, but I can't put my finger on exactly what the problem is. What's strange is that I just now created the `this.Snake ( ) { ... }` function/object, and before that the line `var blockWidth = this.board.getSize().width / this.numBlocks;` inside the `this.placeFood ( ) { ... }` function wasn't causing problems, though I can't see anything fundamentally different about it ..

[CLICK HERE FOR A LIVE EXAMPLE](http://playclassicsnake.com/play)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct about it being a scope issue.  The difference between what you were doing before with `placeFood()` and what you're doing now with `Snake()` is the `new` keyword.

The `new` keyword tells the function to manage its own `this` and so your `Game` context no longer applies to `this` within the `Snake` function.

One solution would be to pass the context into the `Snake` function like this

```
this.snake = new this.Snake(this);
```

and then manage the context in the `Snake` constructor like this

```
this.Snake = function(game) {
  var blockWidth = game.board.getSize().width / game.numBlocks;
  ...
  // replacing `this` with `game` for all relevant properties
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript) for more information on the `new` keyword.

Comment: I thought of that, but doesn't that make a copy of `game` to pass in? I want to avoid unnecessary copies of large elements.

Comment: Javascript passes objects by reference (so you don't have to worry about passing copies of large objects around).  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference) for more on passing by reference vs passing by value.